# move duplicated values into new sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy duplicated values in column "Location ID" and past the same duplicates into a new sheet and name the sheet as the duplicated value using VBA. I have been messing around, and the closest I've gotten is the creation of a list that extracts all duplicate values. Could you please help me with this. e.g.

```
------ Main worksheet ---------
Machine Name    Location ID
A-1             X
A-2             X
A-3             X
B-11            A
B-12            A
C-7             C
C-8             C
```

Should create the following sheets

```
Sheet X
        Machine Name      Location ID
        A-1               X
        A-2               X
        A-3               X

Sheet A
        Machine Name    Location ID
        B-11            A
        B-12            A

Sheet C
        Machine Name    Location ID
        C-7             C
        C-8             C
```

Comment: There are sooo many answers to this question.  One [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621490/if-cell-value-is-specific-size-copy-3-cells-in-that-row-to-new-sheet/34621624#34621624)

Comment: only to find duplicates:

Comment: Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lastRow = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(iCntr, 2) <> "" Then
matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 2), Range("B1:B" & lastRow), 0)
If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
Cells(iCntr, 4) = "Duplicate"
End If
End If
Next
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can split the unique *Location IDs* into a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object's [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etzd1tzc.aspx) while using the dictionary's [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aet97f2.aspx) to hold the records.

> <sup>The following requires a reference be added to [Microsoft Scripting Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat.aspx) in the VBE's Tools, [References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210708.aspx).</sup>

```
Sub split_Locations_to_Worksheets()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, aLOCs As Variant, aTMP As Variant
    Dim dLOCs As New Scripting.Dictionary

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    With Worksheets("Main")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            aLOCs = .Cells.Value2
            For a = LBound(aLOCs, 1) + 1 To UBound(aLOCs, 1)
                If dLOCs.Exists(aLOCs(a, 2)) Then
                    ReDim aTMP(1 To UBound(dLOCs.Item(aLOCs(a, 2)), 1) + 1, 1 To UBound(aLOCs, 2))
                    For b = LBound(dLOCs.Item(aLOCs(a, 2)), 1) To UBound(dLOCs.Item(aLOCs(a, 2)), 1)
                        For c = LBound(dLOCs.Item(aLOCs(a, 2)), 2) To UBound(dLOCs.Item(aLOCs(a, 2)), 2)
                            aTMP(b, c) = dLOCs.Item(aLOCs(a, 2))(b, c)
                        Next c
                    Next b
                    For c = LBound(aLOCs, 2) To UBound(aLOCs, 2)
                        aTMP(b, c) = aLOCs(a, c)
                    Next c
                    dLOCs.Item(aLOCs(a, 2)) = aTMP
                Else
                    ReDim aTMP(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(aLOCs, 2))
                    aTMP(1, 1) = aLOCs(1, 1): aTMP(1, 2) = aLOCs(1, 2)
                    aTMP(2, 1) = aLOCs(a, 1): aTMP(2, 2) = aLOCs(a, 2)
                    dLOCs.Add Key:=aLOCs(a, 2), Item:=aTMP
                End If
            Next a

            For Each aLOCs In dLOCs.keys
                On Error GoTo bm_Need_WS
                With Worksheets("Sheet " & aLOCs)
                    .Cells.ClearContents
                    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(dLOCs.Item(aLOCs), 1), UBound(dLOCs.Item(aLOCs), 2)) = dLOCs.Item(aLOCs)
                End With
            Next aLOCs
        End With
    End With

    GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

bm_Need_WS:
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "Sheet " & aLOCs
        .Visible = True
        With ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 0
            .SplitRow = 1
            .FreezePanes = True
            .Zoom = 80
        End With
    End With
    Resume

bm_Safe_Exit:
    dLOCs.RemoveAll: Set dLOCs = Nothing
    appTGGL
End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub
```

By bulk loading all potential values into a variant array and processing them into another in-memory object, this should process quite quickly. While this is largely designed to accommodate your two-column sample, I've left room in the loops to process larger numbers of columns; you will just have to adjust some of the hard-coded values.