# Show all duplicates in an Excel table's selected column

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

Here is the background:

- Inventory table with 1000 listrows
- One column contains the serial numbers
- I have created a conditional formatting, coloring all duplicates in that column
- However, I would like to **show** all duplicates, in order to compare them to each other
- Since I'm using a table and like using its filter function, **I don't want to hide rows**. Because then, if I cleared all filters in the table, those rows would remain hidden. So I want to avoid that part.

So how do I **show** all duplicates **as a filter** in a table?

Comment: Can you afford to create another column containing the duplication status?

Comment: For a Scipting.Dictionary-based solution see [move duplicated values into new sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841148/move-duplicated-values-into-new-sheets).

Comment: I made it work on my own, without using another column. I think it's cleaner than moving dupes to a new sheet or other similar solutions. This one actually does filter out all singles and only show dupes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ShowDuplicatesInSelectedColumn()
Dim Cel As Range, Rw&, Col&, NoOfOcc&, Rng As Range
Dim Tbl As ListObject, Lst$(1 To 1000), Nr&, LstNr&, AlreadyExists As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    With Tbl

        ' Shows all data rows
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Col = Selection.Column
        Set Rng = .ListColumns(Col).DataBodyRange

        ' Loop through all rows to check for duplicates
        For Rw = .ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set Cel = .ListColumns(Col).DataBodyRange(Rw)

            ' Counts the number of occurences
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                NoOfOcc = 0
                NoOfOcc = .CountIf(Rng, Cel.Value)
            End With

            If NoOfOcc > 1 Then
                ' Check if the value is already in the array
                AlreadyExists = False
                For LstNr = 1 To Nr
                    If Cel.Text = Lst(LstNr) Then AlreadyExists = True
                Next LstNr

                ' If the value wasn't found in the array, we'll add it
                If AlreadyExists = False Then
                    Nr = Nr + 1
                    Lst(Nr) = Cel.Text
                End If
            End If
        Next Rw

        ' Now we'll check how many duplicates that were found
        If Nr = 1 Then
            ' If we only found one duplicate
            With .ListColumns(Col)
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=Col, Criteria1:=Lst(1), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
        ElseIf Nr > 1 Then

            ' Creates an array based on the list that was created above
            ReDim Arr(1 To UBound(Lst))
            For Rw = 1 To Nr
                Arr(Rw) = Lst(Rw)
            Next Rw

            ' Filters all duplicates
            With .ListColumns(Col)
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=Col, Criteria1:=Arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```